# Connection error in Subscription between my SQL Server and Azure database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I'm having a lot of trouble with doing a replication between a SQL Server 2014 and Azure.

I use a remote desktop to connect to the SQL Server machine and there, I start doing all the replication steps. I already made the SQL Server the distributor and then I created a publication. The problem is when I finish the subscription configuration, when I look to the replication monitor, everything is fine (snapshot and log agents) except the subscription job. When I look at the history, the following message description shows:

> 2019-06-04 20:40:36.303 Connecting to Subscriber
>   'MYSERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET' 2019-06-04 20:40:36.744 Agent message
>   code 20084. The process could not connect to Subscriber
>   'MYSERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET'. 2019-06-04 20:40:36.839 Category:NULL
>   Source:  Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Number:  40532
>   Message: Cannot open server "WIN2K8SQL" requested by the login.  The
>   login failed.

`MYSERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET` is Azure and `WIN2K8SQL` is my SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it by verifying that the distributor has db_owner permissions but i never expected that in the subscription login from the publisher server you have to add: @"domain_of_your_subscription_db" next to your login user.

Example: admindb@servername

After doing that, my problem with the subscription connection was solved!